# How to display data from mysql in google charts function?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-visualization

I am trying to use google charts to display some data that is retrieved from a mysql query. This is project is being done in codeigniter. I would like to know how I can display the number that my query is returning. My code is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class RevProgressC extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

    $this->load->model('PaperM');
    $this->load->model('AddRevM');
    $data['rowa']=$this->PaperM->ViewReviewed();


    $this->load->view('RevProgress',$data); 
}


}
?>
```

**Model:**

```
function ViewReviewed()
{

    $this->db->where('status','1');
    $this->db->or_where('status','2');

    $this->db->from('assign');
    $data = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $data;

}
```

**View:**

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.

  //<?php $this->load->model('PaperM');
    //$data['rowa']=$this->PaperM->ViewReviewed();
  //?>

  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Reviewed', 5],
      ['Pending Review', 10]
    ]);

    //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(raw_data);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Reviewed and Not Reviewed Papers',
                   is3D: true,};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Instead of the 5 and 10, I would like to use a php variable that will be holding a value from the above mentioned function. Then pass it onto the script. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change these line..

**On Controller**

`$this->load->view('RevProgress',$data);`

**To**

`$this->load->view('RevProgress',json_encode($data));`

**** AND On view PAge****

`data.addRows([
      ['Reviewed', 5],
      ['Pending Review', 10]
    ]);`

**To**

`data.addRows(<?php echo $RevProgress;?>);`

Comment: Why should I echo $RevProgress? Shouldn't it be echo $data?